# NBA API; How to calculate and plot the shot efficiency of a player vs.the rest of their team?

Tags: python, dataframe, visualization, analytics

I'm trying to compare the shot efficiency of a player vs. the rest of their team. In this case the player and team I'm using for comparison are Giannis Antetokounmpo and the Milwaukee Bucks. I used the code below to succesfully create a shot chart for Giannis I am also able to create a shotchart for his team by importing the teams module from the nba_api ([https://github.com/hkair/nba_api/blob/master/docs/nba_api/][1]). However I am looking for a way to divide the total number of shots made by Giannis over the total number of shots made by his team in each hexbin I've created.

The issue I am having is that I'm not sure about how to isolate the amount of points found in each hexbin from giannis and his team as well as how to properly divide them to create a new dataframe of giannis shot efficiency vs. the rest of the Milwaukee Bucks.

Thanks in advance,

Guled

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import commonplayerinfo, shotchartdetail
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from nba_api.stats.static import players
player_dict = players.get_players()


player_details = [player for player in player_dict if player['full_name'] == 'Giannis Antetokounmpo'][0]



player_num = player_details['id']
player_num

player_info = commonplayerinfo.CommonPlayerInfo(player_id=203507)
player_stats = player_info.player_headline_stats.get_dict()
print(player_stats)


pd.options.display.max_seq_items = 100
shot_chart = shotchartdetail.ShotChartDetail(

player_id = player_num,   
last_n_games=50,
season_nullable='2020-21',
season_type_all_star='Regular Season',

team_id=0,
context_measure_simple='FGA',)


print(shot_chart.get_available_data())
shot_df = shot_chart.shot_chart_detail.get_data_frame()
shot_df.head(20)

MADE = shot_df[shot_df['SHOT_MADE_FLAG']==1]
MADE

MISSED = shot_df[shot_df['SHOT_MADE_FLAG']==0]
MISSED

plt.plot(shot_df.LOC_X, shot_df.LOC_Y,'o',color='black')
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle, Arc

def draw_court(ax=None, color='black', lw=2, outer_lines=False):
    # If an axes object isn't provided to plot onto, just get current one
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # Create the various parts of an NBA basketball court

    # Create the basketball hoop
    # Diameter of a hoop is 18" so it has a radius of 9", whi

ch is a value
    # 7.5 in our coordinate system
    hoop = Circle((0, 0), radius=7.5, linewidth=lw, color=color, fill=False)

    # Create backboard
    backboard = Rectangle((-30, -7.5), 60, -1, linewidth=lw, color=color)

    # The paint
    # Create the outer box 0f the paint, width=16ft, height=19ft
    outer_box = Rectangle((-80, -47.5), 160, 190, linewidth=lw, color=color,
                          fill=False)
    # Create the inner box of the paint, widt=12ft, height=19ft
    inner_box = Rectangle((-60, -47.5), 120, 190, linewidth=lw, color=color,
                          fill=False)

    # Create free throw top arc
    top_free_throw = Arc((0, 142.5), 120, 120, theta1=0, theta2=180,
                         linewidth=lw, color=color, fill=False)
    # Create free throw bottom arc
    bottom_free_throw = Arc((0, 142.5), 120, 120, theta1=180, theta2=0,
                            linewidth=lw, color=color, linestyle='dashed')
    # Restricted Zone, it is an arc with 4ft radius from center of the hoop
    restricted = Arc((0, 0), 80, 80, theta1=0, theta2=180, linewidth=lw,
                     color=color)

    # Three point line
    # Create the side 3pt lines, they are 14ft long before they begin to arc
    corner_three_a = Rectangle((-220, -47.5), 0, 140, linewidth=lw,
                               color=color)
    corner_three_b = Rectangle((220, -47.5), 0, 140, linewidth=lw, color=color)
    # 3pt arc - center of arc will be the hoop, arc is 23'9" away from hoop
    # I just played around with the theta values until they lined up with the 
    # threes
    three_arc = Arc((0, 0), 475, 475, theta1=22, theta2=158, linewidth=lw,
                    color=color)

    # Center Court
    center_outer_arc = Arc((0, 422.5), 120, 120, theta1=180, theta2=0,
                           linewidth=lw, color=color)
    center_inner_arc = Arc((0, 422.5), 40, 40, theta1=180, theta2=0,
                           linewidth=lw, color=color)

    # List of the court elements to be plotted onto the axes
    court_elements = [hoop, backboard, outer_box, inner_box, top_free_throw,
                      bottom_free_throw, restricted, corner_three_a,
                      corner_three_b, three_arc, center_outer_arc,
                      center_inner_arc]

    if outer_lines:
        # Draw the half court line, baseline and side out bound lines
        outer_lines = Rectangle((-250, -47.5), 500, 470, linewidth=lw,
                                color=color, fill=False)
        court_elements.append(outer_lines)

    # Add the court elements onto the axes
    for element in court_elements:
        ax.add_patch(element)
   
    return ax

plt.figure(figsize=(12,11))
draw_court(outer_lines=True)
plt.xlim(-300,300)
plt.ylim(-100,500)
plt.show()



        #This determines the figure's size.
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
    
    # This creates the hex plot, extracting data from the original "shot_df" dataframe and basing the value of the hexagon 
    #    on the mean value of the "SHOT MADE FLAG" column in the table. Items in this line that can be modified to change the
    #    look of the plot:
    
    # gridsize: This changes the amount of hexagons that cover the x- and y-axis. The lower the number, the larger the hexagon.
    
    # vmin, vmax: This changes the min and max of the colour ramp. It's unlikely that a player will have an efficiency higher
    #    than 70%, but you can play with the numbers to see what looks best.
    
    # cmap: You can look up available colour ramps to choose one that you feel represents the data best!
    plot = plt.hexbin(shot_df["LOC_X"],shot_df["LOC_Y"],C=shot_df['SHOT_MADE_FLAG'], gridsize= 25, vmin = 0.0, vmax = 0.75, cmap=plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn'))
    
    # draw the court background.
    draw_court(outer_lines=True)
    
    # Label the colourbar that's on the plot.
    plt.colorbar(label="Percentage of shots made")
    
    
    # Descending values along the axis from left to right. This inverts the data horizontally so that
    #    it shows up correctly on the chart.
    plt.xlim(300, -300)
    plt.ylim(-100, 440) 
    
    img = plt.imread("n:/471/gp381w21a3/fear_the_deer.png")
    plt.imshow(img, extent=[305, -386, -110, 1090])
    # ACTION NEEDED: You're going to need to make a title here based on the player you selected. For example:
    #   It could be "Shot efficiency for Kyle Lowry during the 2018-19 playoffs"
    plt.title("Player:" "Giannis Antetokounmpo")
    
    # ACTION NEEDED: Add Data Scource and Author
    plt.text(300,-200,'Data Source: stats.nba.com')
            
    
    # Show the plot.
    plt.show()


  [1]: https://github.com/hkair/nba_api/blob/master/docs/nba_api/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty loaded question. My suggestion is just post 1 question at a time in sperate posts. So I'll answer this with sort of the first part:

You'll have to get all of the Bucks shot charts, (not just GA's) to be able to calculate that difference.

So we'll adjust the parameters a bit (change player_id to 0, and team_id to 1610612749 which is for the Bucks). Then you can separate them into GA shot chart, and then the rest of the team.

Your next part is then to to a subplot (side by side chart) of GA's shot figure on left, and the rest of the teams on the right.

But first heres how you'd get both those datasets:

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import commonplayerinfo, shotchartdetail
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from nba_api.stats.static import players
player_dict = players.get_players()


player_details = [player for player in player_dict if player['full_name'] == 'Giannis Antetokounmpo'][0]


player_num = player_details['id']
player_num

player_info = commonplayerinfo.CommonPlayerInfo(player_id=203507)
player_stats = player_info.player_headline_stats.get_dict()
print(player_stats)


pd.options.display.max_seq_items = 100
shot_chart = shotchartdetail.ShotChartDetail(
player_id = 0,   
last_n_games=50,
season_nullable='2020-21',
season_type_all_star='Regular Season',
team_id=1610612749,
context_measure_simple='FGA',)


print(shot_chart.get_available_data())
shot_df = shot_chart.shot_chart_detail.get_data_frame()
shot_df.head(20)

# Get specific player shot chart
player_made_df = shot_df[(shot_df['SHOT_MADE_FLAG']==1) & (shot_df['PLAYER_ID']==player_num)]
player_missed_df = shot_df[(shot_df['SHOT_MADE_FLAG']==0) & (shot_df['PLAYER_ID']==player_num)]

# Get rest of team shot chart
rest_of_team_made_df = shot_df[(shot_df['SHOT_MADE_FLAG']==1) & (shot_df['PLAYER_ID']!=player_num)]
rest_of_team_missed_df = shot_df[(shot_df['SHOT_MADE_FLAG']==0) & (shot_df['PLAYER_ID']!=player_num)]
```